# Oracle Apex Modal Dialog Link being wrongly transformed

Tags: oracle, templates, plsql, oracle-apex

I've got an Oracle **Apex 18.1** Dialog which is via Javascript.
Inside of that Modal Dialog there is a **Classic Report** Region, which shows a bunch of Images which have a hyperlink attached to them. The **Template** I use looks like this:

```
<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:40:&APP_SESSION.::NO:RP:P40_VIDEOID:#VIDEOID#">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/#VIDEOID#/mqdefault.jpg" width="210" height="118"> 
</a>
```

The problem is, that Apex transforms that link before the Modal Dialog gets opened into something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,'f?p=100:40:4815510542999:::::');::NO:RP:P40_VIDEOID:vFZHArtFt8Y" class="WATCHED_VIDEO_0">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/vFZHArtFt8Y/mqdefault.jpg" width="210" height="118"> 
</a>
```

And that **breaks** the Page, because the Javascript there is invalid - the Item Parameter is not replaced and thus the Link is not working.

What do I have to do, to get apex to include that Item Value?

Comment: do you build this link in the sql query? if, yes. try to build using apex_util.prepare_url. SELECT '<a href="' || apex_util.prepare_url .... || '"' ....

Comment: Well it's part of a template so I kinda can't do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can create the url in your select and use then in your template. In your sql you create the URL with APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL and name the column as url

```
SELECT
...,
APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(
    p_url => 'f?p=' || :APP_ALIAS || ':40:' || :APP_SESSION ||'::NO::P40_VIDEOID:' || mytable.video_id,
    p_checksum_type => 'SESSION') as url
FROM
mytable
```

In your temmplate you can use the url value like you are using #VIDEOID#

```
<a href="#URL#">
    <img src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/#VIDEOID#/mqdefault.jpg" width="210" height="118"> 
</a>
```

Comment: Sadly with that approach it's still the same problem. The Item ID gets stripped: javascript:apex.navigation.dialog.close(true,'f?p=100:40:2291872617387'); The only "advantage" the javscript is technically valid now - its just still not what I need

Comment: I updated the answer with apex_util.prepare_url to your case

Comment: I didn't use the checksum argument, thats the dealbreaker, thx!